# Multiple thread error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an app where I need to use AsyncTask but I am having the issue that the main thread is going too far and ends up crashing my app because my Connect1 thread has not retrieved the information yet needed to continue.  I was wondering how could I have the thread wait till the AsyncTask thread dies out and then the main thread can continue.

Code:

```
private void gNameOriginTag() {

    TextView tV;

    Connect1 connect1 = new Connect1();
    connect1.execute();

    // Set the long name for the chosen.
    tV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gLName);
    tV.setText(columns.get(4));      //<<<< Error is here.

    ....
}
```

Connect1 AsyncTask:

```
private class Connect1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // STEP 4: Execute a query
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // STEP 5a: Extract data from result set
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM gs WHERE name ='"
                    + gSelected + "'");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            int x = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                while (x < rsmd.getColumnCount()) {

                    // Retrieve Strings & Add it to the ArrayList.
                    columns.add(rs.getString(x));
                    x++;
                }

            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }// nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }// end finally try
        }// end try

        return "";
    }
}
```

The reason why I am doing this is because android 2.3.3 doesn't run mysql on the main thread from what I learned so I am trying to learn AsyncTask, so what I am trying to accomplish in "Code:" is somehow make the main thread wait/join (I also read up that pausing the main thread is bad so I am even more lost on what to do) up for the Connect1 thread to finish so that:

```
tV.setText(columns.get(4));
```

can be retrieved so my app does not crash.

Comment: Put the code you need run after the AsyncTask is over in onPostExecute().

Comment: move `tV.setText(columns.get(4));` instead onPostExecute() method method

Comment: afetr asynk.execute(), Asyntask start doInBackGround() as thread,and after it finish onPostExecute() call, this run in main thread, you should write all your UI updations inside on post, it work as handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method that is called by the AsyncTask when it is finished and that is then run on the UIThread again.

MainThread: calls AsyncTask

AsyncTask: does the work and calls doWhenDoneWithBackgroundWork

doWhenDoneWithBackgroundWork: does some work on MainThread again

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code on `onPostExecute` method of Async task.